# CSS Invert colors for IE

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I am trying to invert the colors to images. It works fine on Chrome and Firefox but not for IE11. Here is the CSS code that I am using for the image.

```
.img {
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    -o-filter: invert(100%);
    -moz-filter: invert(100%);
    -ms-filter: invert(100%);
    filter: invert(100%);
}
```

I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253442/internet-explorer-and-safari-mobile-css-filter-invert) to the same question I am asking but it doesn't say how to implement it. Here is the code for it:

```
function invert_img(rgb) {
  rgb = [].slice.call(arguments).join(",").replace(/rgb\(|\)|rgba\(|\)|\s/gi, '').split(','); //locate different values of rgb
  for (var counter = 0; counter < rgb.length; counter++)
    rgb[counter] = (counter === 3 ? 1 : 255) - rgb[counter];
  return rgb.join(", ");
}

console.log(
  invert_img("rgb(150, 0, 0)"), // 0, 150,150
  invert_img("12, 0, 0"), // 0, 12, 12
  invert_img(25, 0, 0) // 0, 25, 25
);
```

I tried putting this in between script tags in the head section of my ASP.NET Master Page. I tried changing the JS code from `invert_img` to `img` and it didn't work. Please let me know how to do so.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253442/internet-explorer-and-safari-mobile-css-filter-invert

Comment: its because the answer you read is have nothing to do with invert color on images using css, the user that answer have been suspended for voting regulations. So the answer you have is not work for sure. Now if the browser did not support it, and you can nof find any magic trick with IE then you probably can't do it

Comment: take a look here ie10+  https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

Comment: and here http://www.cssjunction.com/plugins/css3-filter-invert-support-in-internet-explorer-10/